# Automated posting of links to Facebook fan page via app

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to enable automated posting of links to news articles when they are published on an external site (which happens without any user input).

From what I've gathered, an app on Facebook can't manage a fan page directly - only through a manager of that page with the `manage_pages` permission. This means generating an access token for a manager first in order to obtain a page access code (with a maximum lifespan of 2 months).

It's really awkward to have to manually generate a new token (even if it just means logging in again) whenever the old one expires. Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extendingpagetokens

Comment: Thanks. Not sure how I missed that. I was under the assumption that extending an already extended access token worked the same for users as pages (i.e. return the same token back)